# How to remove a substring that starts and ends with certain characters in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this

```
foldername/pic.jpg
```

How can I remove this part `/pic` so the new string will become `foldername.jpg`?

EDIT: I want to replace any string that starts with `/` and end with `.` with a dot (.) so the new file name only contains the foldername.jpg

Comment: `s.replace("/pic", "")`

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to remove the part starts with slash until a dot or is it always `/pic`?

Comment: I added an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module. Try -

```
import re
a = 'foldername/pic.jpg'
out = re.sub(r'/.*\.', r'.', a)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

if that is all you have, you can do it like this:

```
name = 'foldername/pic.jpg'
root = name.split('/')[0]
ext = name.split('.')[1]
name = root + ext
```

but if you are splitting file-paths, you will be better off with `os.path` commands, for example:

```
import os
name = 'foldername/pic.jpg'
root = os.path.dirname(name)
_, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
name = root + '.' + ext
```

both cases return a string `foldername.jpg` in these cases, but the `os.path` commands are more flexible

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution, try regular expressions.
In your specific example, I will make the assumption you want to remove a substring that starts with '/', and ends with 'c' (ie, /pic).

```
In [394]: import re
In [395]: re.sub(r'(.+)\/\w+c(.+)', r'\1\2', 'foldername/pic.jpg')
Out[395]: 'foldername.jpg'
```

Just note that the second argument needs the raw string encapsulator r'  ', if you want to interpolate variables, else the \1 or \2 have no effect.